# Adicionar o mesmo produto em varias categorias

Tags: php, mysql

Boas

E o seguinte eu tenho uma tabela categorias e outra tabela produtos neste momento ao criar o produto seleciono a categoria a que ele pertence por selectbox só que agora tenho a necessidade de associar um produtos a varias categorias gostava de saber qual pode ser a melhor forma de associar o mesmo produto a varias categorias.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estabelecimentos` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_mae` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`titulo` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`slug` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`link_facebook` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`link_mapa` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`distritos` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`concelhos` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`morada` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`contacto` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`int_preco` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`link_site` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`introducao` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`servicos` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`descricao` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`keywords` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`keywords_pesquisa` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`google_verification` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`activo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`pos` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=198 ;
```

Comment: bancos de dados é MyISAM

Comment: É possível fazer com `MyISAM` também, mas ficaria vinculado a um "Model" no PHP. Em bancos de dados mais relacionais (como `innoDB`) você usaria o `1:N` (one-to-many), mas também poderia usar many-to-many seria algo como: https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/73/javaee/ecommerce/data-model/many-to-many.png

Comment: Então será melhor converter a base de dados para innoDB e melhor ?

Comment: Ok então como poderia fazer por um model em php mantendo a mesma estrutura que tenho no banco acima

Comment: Eu já tenho backoffice e front-end neste momento eu faço o insert mas só para uma categoria por meio de selectbox queria e implementar para mais que uma categoria

Comment: Sim César, entendo, realmente eu quis lhe dizer que você precisaria de uma tabela com as categorias e uma com os produtos, o back-end (que é diferente de backoffice) e o front-end (que é html, javascript) seria exemplos de como fazer o processo.

Comment: Consegue me ajudar a criar isso preciso mesmo de fazer esse sistema

Comment: Boa noite César, realmente é um sistema que demanda um certo tempo para desenvolver e ainda formular isto como uma boa resposta. Não é que eu não queira, é que no momento eu não irei conseguir fazer algo realmente funcional em pouco tempo. Mas prometo ver se arrumo um tempo e se sou realmente capaz de criar algo útil :)

Comment: Uma solução que estava a pensar era inserir um array com as categorias na coluna do artigo

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é usar uma entidade fraca para tal, supondo o modelo

```
categorias
----------
categoria_id
categoria_nome

produtos
---------
produtos_id
produtos_nome

categorias_produtos
--------------------
categorias_produtos_id
produto_id
categoria_id
```

Sendo que ficaria

```
categorias 1 -------- * categorias_produtos * ---------- 1 produtos
```

Comment: A minha estrutura dos produtos coloquei acima no tópico em que o campo id_mae e onde leva o nome da categoria actualmente esta assim queria uma forma de não ter de mudar muito a estrutura

Comment: A resposta de Adir e a boa resposta. O que vc tem como problema e comum: produtos, fornecedores mais um fornecedor pode vender mas de um produto e vc pode comprar o mesmo produto em varias fornecedores. A solução e ter uma terceira tabela que faz o link entre fornecedor e produtos (e vice-versa). O seu problema e que vc fiz a tabela antes de pensar sobre isso. Agora, infelizmente, acho que precisa mudar a estrutura.

Comment: Mas dessa forma insiro a categoria_id num array seprado por virgulas ?